# TeamsFx CLI preview not loading the app in MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I used Teams Toolkit to create a messaging extension app. It's manifest.json is here:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.16/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.16",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "${{TEAMS_APP_ID}}",
  "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.extension",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Teams App, Inc.",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.example.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.example.com/termofuse",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.example.com/privacy"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "teams-app-${{TEAMSFX_ENV}}",
    "full": "full name for teams-app"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "short description of teams-app",
    "full": "full description of teams-app"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "${{BOT_ID}}",
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "${{BOT_ID}}",
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "addTask",
          "context": [
            "message"
          ],
          "description": "Test command to run action on message context",
          "title": "Add",
          "type": "action",
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "summary",
              "title": "Summary",
              "description": "Edit Summary",
              "inputType": "text"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "messageHandlers": [
        {
          "type": "link",
          "value": {
            "domains": [
              "*.botframework.com"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "configurableTabs": [],
  "staticTabs": [],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "auth.abcd.com"
  ]
}
```

This is my
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHP3N.png)

In Teams sample apps on github, it is instructed to run 3 commands for the app using teamsfx cli, `teamsfx provision, deploy and preview`.
All commands show done, but in `teamsfx preview --env local` the app opens like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehLvA.png)

There is no "Add" button now, also it looks like it is not reading `manifest.json` file.
It was working a few days ago without any issues.

I tried uploading the .zip file to teams, it's working, but it won't connect to any domain (even if I specify those in `validDomains`.

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5MVf.png)